# Tuleap shows: “Project Homepage not found, codendi_aliases.conf not present”

Tags: tuleap

I have set up a Tuleap server, everything was installed with no errors.
Working in a project, the project-homepage is not found.

So I searched the web and tried to follow the instruction to edit the `codendi_aliases.conf` in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/`. This doesn't work for me, because there is no `codendi_aliases.conf` file on my system.

Comment: What is the content of /etc/httpd/conf.d ?

Comment: Here ist the list of the content of conf.d:auth_mysql.conf       php.conf              tuleap-aliases
auth_mysql.conf.orig  php.conf.orig         tuleap-plugins
auth_mysql.conf.rhel  php.conf.rhel         tuleap-svnroot.conf
ckeditor.conf         README                tuleap-svnroot.conf.old
ckeditor.conf.rhel    ssl.conf              tuleap-vhost.conf
mailman.conf          ssl.conf.rhel         viewvc.conf
mod_dnssd.conf        subversion.conf       welcome.conf
mod_dnssd.conf.rhel   subversion.conf.orig  welcome.conf.rhel
perl.conf             subversion.conf.rhel , THX!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I solved it with following steps:

1. Create the `codendi_aliases.conf` file:

   ```
   touch /etc/httpd/conf.d/codendi_aliases.conf
   ```
2. Edit the `codendi_aliases.conf` file and add:

   ```
   AliasMatch ^/www/([^/]*)/(.*) /home/groups/$1/htdocs/$2
   ```
3. Restart the service:

   ```
   service httpd restart
   ```